# How can I set up Ubuntu 14.04 to automatically go to the lock screen after a certain time period regardless of activity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I set up Ubuntu 14.04 to automatically go to the lock screen after a certain time period regardless of activity? (ie to child-lock a machine so s/he's not glued to it all night)

Comment: If s/he can use the computer unsupervised, s/he can undo anything you can do. This is a people problem, and technical solutions will only have a limited  benefit. Have you tried telling him/her that the computer is off-limits after a certain time?

Comment: The person I'm particularly concerned about won't be able to undo anything. (mentally disabled 31 year old)

Comment: Maybe turning off the internet at your router after x o'clock might be an option too, wouldn't stop local programs like solitaire or minesweeper though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TimeKpr](https://launchpad.net/timekpr)? It appears to allow you to limit access by time, but I've not tried it personally:

[image: Time Configuration Window]

[Installation Instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/install-timekpr-parental-control-app-in.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjasnik/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timekpr
```